# Building rails Form and Form_Fields on the fly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, activerecord

On a Rails3 project , I have a requirement where i have to build the form based on the fields & labels that are already saved in the database and i want to save the values  in to other tables with other associated records with FORM_FIELD id.

I have a table FORM_FIELDS( name , label  ,field_type ) with name of the field , label and its type like text_area ,text_field , integer etc.

I want to build the FORM with fields that will have name , label and type based on the records i choose from the FORM_FIELDS table.

How do i build this form Syntactically correct? ,  Can anyone please help me out with this design?

Answer (score 0):

Use formtastic gem for doing this on the fly.

Comment: but fortastic works only with For_for and not form_tag . Or is it not the case?? thats the reason i didnt research further on it!
and the form data collected from this form will be saved over two tables.